# Help with my training data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on my first NN following a tensorflow tut and trying to use my own data.
After about 80 attempts of formatting my data and trying to load it into a dataset to train I'm throwing the towel.

Here is how my data currently looks

```
syslog_data = [
[302014,0,0,63878,30,3,1], [302014,0,0,3891,0,0,0], [302014,0,0,15928,0,0,2], [305013,5,0,123,99999,0,3],
[302014,0,0,5185,0,0,0], [305013,5,0,123,99999,0,3], [302014,0,0,56085,0,0,0], [110002,4,2,50074,99999,0,4],
```

In this the last item in each list is the label.
If you can tell me if I need to reformat my data and how or just how to get it loaded into a dataset properly.

Thanks for any help or advice you can give

Here is the full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from . import syslog

print(tf.VERSION)
print(tf.keras.__version__)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

dataset = tf.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices(syslog)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

Comment: WElcome to Data Science SE!  Which tutorial did you follow? What error are you actually getting? Have you read the [**Keras documentation**](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)? Or the relevant Tensorflow docs for [**from_tensor_slices**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices)?

Comment: Ive followed about 15 :/ but this one is the most relevant https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras I have received a number of errors from different attempts. the most recent is this - got shape [8972], but wanted [8972, 1]. from this code dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels)). Im pretty lost on what my training data should look like and how i should import it.

Comment: I can reformat as needed, I just dont know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems and things you might want to add to your existing script.

Below I separate your example data into two NumPy arrays:

- input values `x`
- labels `y`

It is also important to make sure they are of type `float32`, because Tensorflow will complain if you pass it integers (as they otherwise would be interpreted).

The following works for me, the model trains to completion:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

syslog_data = [
    [302014, 0, 0, 63878, 30, 3, 1],
    [302014, 0, 0, 3891, 0, 0, 0],
    [302014, 0, 0, 15928, 0, 0, 2],
    [305013, 5, 0, 123, 99999, 0, 3],
    [302014, 0, 0, 5185, 0, 0, 0],
    [305013, 5, 0, 123, 99999, 0, 3],
    [302014, 0, 0, 56085, 0, 0, 0],
    [110002, 4, 2, 50074, 99999, 0, 4],
]

print(tf.VERSION)
print(tf.keras.__version__)

x = np.array([arr[:-1] for arr in syslog_data], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([arr[-1:] for arr in syslog_data], dtype=np.float32)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

Comment: I know we just met but I love you

Answer (score 1):

```
import keras
import numpy as np
full_data = np.array(syslog_data)
X = full_data[:,:6]
Y = full_data[:,6]
# Convert labels to categorical one-hot encoding
one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y, num_classes=10)

model.fit(X,Y, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

Does this work? I think I might be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: I didnt under stand that it needed to be an array, thank you for replying